# Efficiency of the insulation of a house

Tags: thermodynamics, dissipation

I had an argument about the most cost-effective way to keep the energy bill low in the winter (here, temperature usually have an average of -20°C (-4°F)).

He thinks that it's more effective to keep a temperature at a constant temperature at say 24°C (75.2°F), because It would cost as much or more to re-heat the house if you let the temperature drop.

I simply think that the lower the temperature the better, because heat from the house will dissipate less and you need less energy to maintant the temperature.

Am-I right? if so, which scientific theory could I look at to my make point?

Answer (score 1):

You are right: it's more energy efficient to lower the temperature at night (or in general). The total energy loss is simply the thermal resistance of your house (which is constant) times the temperature difference between the inside and the outside. The lower the temperature difference, the lower the loss.

Of course, it does take energy to heat the house back up the higher temperature in the morning but this easily offset by the energy you save during the "cool down" period at night. In other words you put energy in in the morning, but you get that back in the evening when the house drifts down to the lower temperature. During that time, the furnaces is off for an extended period of time. At night you save because the temperature difference is lower.

If you are reasonably familiar with circuit modeling, you can easily do the exact math: Model the furnace as a current source, the heat capacity of the house as a capacitor and the thermal resistance as a resistor, all in parallel. The voltage across the resistor is the temp difference from outside to inside.

Comment: In general, I agree.   But, if everybody gets up and leaves, then you wasted energy heating the house, to recool with nobody home.   So put clothes on, and forget heating the house.   A related situation is the temperature of your hot water.   You should run your hot water heater (tank type), at just the temperature you need to shower, so that you shower in the hot water with ZERO cold water added.   Then your lower temperature water, loses less heat sitting in the tank, or flowing through the pipe.   If you heat the water to 160 F, and mix it with cold for 98.6 F , you waste energy.

Answer (score 0):

My students often found analogies that used money easier to grasp, so you might try this:

You are driving 100 km along a very strange toll road.  Every 10 km you pass through a toll booth, where you pay a toll of 10% of the cash you have in the car. (You have $\$$1000 cash at the start of the toll road) Just after each toll booth, there is a drive-thru ATM, where you can, if you wish, withdraw from your bank account the cash you just paid out.

Should you replace the money after each toll booth or wait until after the last toll booth?

It's easy to see, and calculate, that the benefit comes from the reduced toll on your reduced cash. just as the home benefits from the reduced losses from a cooler house...